# HLSL Shader help

Tags: hlsl

I'm trying to go over some Shader code at my university, I have forgotten it, and well, Its really confusing, The documentation we have been given is really difficult to read.

Also is there any good beginner tutorials In HLSL that can walk me through  the whole thing ?

```
void RenderScene( float updateTime )
{
    // Setup the viewport - defines which part of the back-buffer we will render to (usually all of it)
    D3D10_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width  = BackBufferWidth;
    vp.Height = BackBufferHeight;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    g_pd3dDevice->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );



    //************************************************
    // FIRST RENDER PASS - Render scene to texture

    // Specify that the scene texture will be the render target in this first pass (rather than the backbuffer), will share the depth/stencil buffer with the backbuffer though
    g_pd3dDevice->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, /* MISSING */ , DepthStencilView );
    /*MISSING - specify scene texture as render target (variables near top of file)*/
    // Clear the texture and the depth buffer
    g_pd3dDevice->ClearRenderTargetView( SceneRenderTarget, &AmbientColour.r );
    g_pd3dDevice->ClearDepthStencilView( DepthStencilView, D3D10_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0 );

    // Prepare camera
    MainCamera->SetAspect( static_cast<TFloat32>(BackBufferWidth) / BackBufferHeight );
    MainCamera->CalculateMatrices();
    MainCamera->CalculateFrustrumPlanes();

    // Set camera and light data in shaders
    SetCamera( MainCamera );
    SetAmbientLight( AmbientColour );
    SetLights( &Lights[0] );

    // Render entities and draw on-screen text
    EntityManager.RenderAllEntities( MainCamera );

    //************************************************
```

I'm really not sure whats to go in OMSSetRenderTarget, it has aweird parameter that has Variable * const *variable which I try replicating with the values I have been given and it returns an error.

Comment: Are you sure that's HLSL? Looks like plain old C++11 to me. Maybe that's why you're having problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [online documentation of `OMSetRenderTargets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476464(v=vs.85).aspx), then you'll see that the second argument should be of type `ID3D11RenderTargetView * const *` and is named `ppRenderTargetViews`, which is a pointer to a pointer of render target views (most likely an array of pointers to render target views).

It's clear that the intended variable is `SceneRenderTarget`, but without knowing the type of `SceneRenderTarget` (whether it's a struct or a pointer) I couldn't tell you what `/*Missing*/` should be. Thankfully I can check the [online documentation of `ClearRenderTargetView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476388(v=vs.85).aspx) to discover that its type is `ID3D11RenderTargetView *`, so I can deduce that as `OMSetRenderTargets` needs a `ID3D11RenderTargetView * const *` (a pointer to a pointer) and `SceneRenderTarget` is a pointer, you just need to take the address of `SceneRenderTarget` to have a valid argument, leaving the answer as:

```
g_pd3dDevice->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &SceneRenderTarget, DepthStencilView );
```

(Next time you get a problem of type 'fill in the missing argument', always check the documentation to discover the expected type of the argument and what the expected argument represents.)

Comment: Odd I tried putting that in and it didn't work, it throws an exception.

Comment: @RNewell122 Specifically which exception?

Comment: Oh I am rather sorry, i misunderstood the *const* that  it requires an &SceneRenderTarget instead of SceneRenderTarget

Comment: @RNewell122 `ID3D11RenderTargetView * const *` means 'pointer to const pointer to `ID3D11RenderTargetView`', `SceneRenderTarget` is a `ID3D11RenderTargetView *` (a 'pointer to `ID3D11RenderTargetView`'), so `&SceneRenderTarget` is a 'pointer to pointer to `ID3D11RenderTargetView`', but the const can be added implicitly, so it still matches the signature of `ID3D11RenderTargetView * const *`. Is it working or is it still causing an exception? (And if it is, what is the error message?)